# C# Crystal Report printing original report page size ignored

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am creating application in c# to print Crystal report rpt with the following code.

```
ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
rptDoc.Load(rptlocation);
rptDoc.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "Printername";
rptDoc.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
```

The issue here is that when printed, the page becomes full A4 (filling half top and half empty below), as well as when exported to PDF. The result I expect is it should print as given, but it seems ignoring the original page size, which is half.

It's worth noting that the page size of the original rpt is half A4. When previewed in Crystal Report, it is in half too which is correct. And an export to PDF, too it is correct.

Anyone pls help. Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you set Printer settings in the report itself?? There is a check box to Automatically detect settings. Did you try using that instead.

Comment: I'm printing using the mentioned code. Where can I find or set the check box option?

Answer (score 0):

Right click anywhere within the crystal report then select "Design", then click the "page setup" then the option where you can select whether to use your default printers settings or not.